OpenIddict Introspection + .net Aspire (Service Discovery)
I'm trying to get introspection working with .net Aspire Integration tests, which use random ports for everything.  In regular mode the port is consistent and thus setting the issuer using the standard https://localhost:3432 works fine.
But 3432 changes in integration tests, and I can't figure out how to get OpenIddict to play ball despite having it do this:
options.SetIssuer("https://accounts");
options.UseIntrospection();
options.UseSystemNetHttp();

and in ServiceDefaults we have the standard:
builder.Services.ConfigureHttpClientDefaults(http =>
{
    // Turn on resilience by default
    http.AddStandardResilienceHandler();


    // Turn on service discovery by default
    http.AddServiceDiscovery();
});

I would think that this would result in the right requests going to the right place, but unfortunately, it just gets a connection refused and doesn't appear to use the right ports etc that were injected with Service Discovery.
Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
